# Advice for keeping tzitzit away from the toilet

Tags: tzitzis, bathroom, how-to

When I sit on the toilet (especially public toilets with a long "snout"), I often find myself in an uncomfortable situation trying to keep my tzitzit away from the bowl.

My strategy has always been to wear my beged longer in the front so that the rear tzitzit stay safe and under control, and then pull up the longish front tzitzit along with my shirt.  Although this works all right, I'm wondering if anyone has a better approach.

If it matters, I'm a slender guy and I wear tzitzit tucked in.

Comment: Take all tiztis bring it to the front of you then stuff it in your shirt and roll up it should stay in place and nothing gets in way

Comment: @sam i do the same. Works like a charm

Comment: @Sam I thought I patented that!

Comment: @sam No need to even bring to the front, just take front and back and put in your shirt seperately, and roll up the shirt on both sides!

Comment: @ShoelU'Meishiv Nope, I did. :)

Comment: Take them off before going in or hold them

Answer (score 2):

Yeah. So, pull on your shirt bottom front until you get a nice shirt-bun and then wrap your tzitzis around your shirt-bun then roll up to your stomach.
It works like a charm

Comment: [sam](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48016/advice-for-keeping-tzitzit-away-from-the-toilet/81370?noredirect=1#comment126654_48016) wrote this 2 1/2 years ago.

Comment: That's what's done

Answer (score 0):

You can try holding all the *tzitzis* as you would by *shema*, although that would leave you with only one free hand to do whatever else you need to do.

Comment: You're only supposed to wipe with one hand anyway (OC 3), so this doesn't seem to be an issue.

Comment: @DonielF If you're using an object (no your bare hand) you can use any hand you like.